# make sbt build fail on scalastyle warnings

Tags: scala, sbt, scalastyle

I'm enforcing scalastyle check to my code space, referring http://www.scalastyle.org/sbt.html.

in build.sbt:

```
// scalastyle check
lazy val compileScalastyle = taskKey[Unit]("compileScalastyle")
compileScalastyle := org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin.scalastyle.in(Compile).toTask("").value
(compile in Compile) <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn compileScalastyle
```

in project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" %% "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "0.8.0")
```

When I run `sbt compile`, scalastyle is generating `[warning] ***./utils/ConfigManager.scala: File must end with newline character`, but **compile still succeeded**.

Is there a way to make `sbt compile` **fail on scalastyle warnings**?

I just change all `<check level="warning" ...>` to be `<check level="error" ...>` in `scalastyleGenerateConfig`, I'm not sure this is the right way to do it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are really only two simple options that I can think of.

The obvious one is to change your scalastyle config so that the warnings you want to cause build failure are errors. That's really what the scalastyle config is for. If you want something to be treated as an error, call it one! `<check level="error" ...>` will give you the least amount of headache.

Otherwise, the only simple way to promote a warning to an error in sbt is to use the `-Xfatal-warnings` flag:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xfatal-warnings")
```

But that will convert *all* warnings in your project to errors, scalastyle or not.

Answer (score 1):

The sbt plugin also has 2 relevant configurations mentioned in [docs](http://www.scalastyle.org/sbt.html):

1. scalastyleFailOnWarning which has default value false
2. scalastyleFailOnError which has default true (docs says false but code says true)